# import en python: evitar usar el nombre del archivo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo esta jerarquía de directorios/archivos:

> python/
>     test.py
>     t3io/
>         agent.py
>         common.py

El contenido de los archivos es:

> python/test.py

```
import t3io.agent

t3io = t3io.Agent( )
```

> python/t3io/common.py

```
class Exit:
    __init__( self ):
        pass

class Signal:
    __init__( self ):
        pass
```

> python/t3io/agent.py

```
from . common import *

class Agent:
    def __init__( self ):
        pass
```

En C++, el *contenedor físico* (archivo con el código) es independiente del *contenedor lógico* (el `namespace`). Quisiera obtener algo parecido en python; desde el directorio `python`, intento

> $>python test.py
>
> AttributeError: module 't3io' has no attribute 'Agent'

Es decir, en python, necesito usar un *contenedor* adicional:

```
t3io = t3io.agent.Agent( )
```

- ¿ Como puedo evitar el uso del nombre del archivo al usar símbolos presentes en él ?

Comment: Aunque entiendo qué preguntas, el código que has puesto no produce el error que comentas. ¿Puedes completar el código python para ver porqué te falla?

Comment: Pues tienes razón ... juraría que mostraba el error indicado ... Se ve que durante las pruebas perdí el hilo. Arreglado. Lamento la equivocación.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varias alternativas para lograr lo que pretendes, según qué tengas en mente:

### Evitar un "nivel adicional"

En `test.py` puedes simplemente poner:

```
from t3io import agent

t3io = agent.Agent( )
```

### Que fucione *exactamente* la sintaxis que tenías

Es decir, que funcione el poner `t3io = t3io.Agent()`

Lo primero decir que quizás llamar a la variable `t3io`, ya que ese es el mismo nombre que el módulo/paquete que estás importando, no me parece la mejor idea, pues puede causar todo tipo de confusiones. En cualquier caso, lo siguiente funcionaría, si bien es una chapuza que desaconsejo:

```
import t3io.agent as t3io

t3io = t3io.Agent()
```

La sintaxis `import X as Y` te permite "renombrar" el espacio de nombres para que no sea necesariamente el mismo que el del módulo importado. De este modo el módulo que importamos (`t3io.agent`) se renombra como `t3io`, por lo que ya podrás hacer luego `t3io.Agent()`. En cualquier caso, ya que seguidamente asignas el resultado a una variable `t3io`, estás perdiendo ese espacio de nombres y en el resto del script ya no podrás referirte a `t3io` para acceder a más clases o variables del módulo importado, ya que `t3io` será a partir de ese punto la variable que contiene el objeto `Agent`.

### Importando sub-modulos en el paquete "principal"

La carpeta `t3io` es técnicamente un "paquete" por contener en su interior varios submódulos. Al ser un paquete puede contener un fichero llamado `__init__.py` (de hecho la existencia de ese fichero era obligatoria en versiones anteriores de python, aunque estuviera vacío, como "marcador"  de que esa carpeta era un paquete).

Si ese fichero existe, se ejecutará cuando desde el programa principal hagas `import t3io`. Por tanto dentro de ese `__init__.py` puedes hacer `import` de otras clases que quieras hacer "visibles" desde el nivel superior del paquete, aunque estén implementadas en submódulos.

Es decir, puedes hacer que `t3io/__init__.py` contenga lo siguiente:

```
# Esto es python/t3io/__init__.py
from .agent import Agent
```

Y entonces en el programa principal podrás hacer:

```
# Esto es python/test.py
import t3io

t3io = t3io.Agent()
```

El `import t3io` ejecutará `t3io/__init__.py` y creará el espacio de nombres `t3io` con el resultado. Como consecuencia ese espacio de nombres contendrá `Agent` porque en el `__init__.py` lo hemos importado desde su sub-módulo.

Creo que esta solución es la mejor (descontando que tiene el mismo problema antes mencionado relativo a la variable que has llamado `t3io`, igual que al paquete)

Comment: No lo puedo probar ahora mismo ... pero lo haré lo antes posible. Gracias :-)